# интеллектуальный парсинг сайтов

Tags: php, python, парсер

Задача такая, чтобы парсер сам выдергивал ссылки на статьи, новости и т.д. с сайта. То есть без указания ему регулярок, xpath и т.д. То есть определенный алгоритм, который самостоятельно распознает именно ссылки на новости. Чтобы пропускал мимо ссылки на рубрики, категории и т.д. У newspaper нашел такое, но ему удается это проделать не с каждым сайтом. То есть где то он находит 200 линков, а где то всего лишь 1. Буду благодарен за любую наводку, может какие то библиотеки, хотя мне кажется я все пересмотрел

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону нейронной сети и обучение искусственного интеллекта

Comment: Вариантов только два - либо мощная система эвристик, либо машинное обучение. Ну, либо какое-то сочетание этих двух подходов. Но в любом случае - это очень много работы квалифицированного специалиста.

Comment: Ссылки не распознаешь точно если не знаешь содержимого того, куда они ведут, так что в любом случае придётся делать мини-обработчик и выяснять тип содержимого.

Comment: Сайты с микроразметкой schema.org можно парсить по одному шаблону, но ее используют далеко не все.